# zf2 - url view helper: specify parameters for route

Tags: php, zend-framework2, zend-route

My main router goes like this (simplified):

```
'router' => [
    'routes' => [
        'blog' => [
            'type'         => 'regex',
            'options'      => [
                'regex'         => "/(?<language>[a-z]{2})?",
                'spec'          => "/%language%",
                'defaults'      => [
                    'controller' => 'Blog\Controller\Posts',
                    'action'     => 'index'
                ],
            ],
            'may_terminate' => true,
            'child_routes' => [
           // [...] 
                        'add_post'    => [
                            'type'    => 'literal',
                            'options' => [
                                'route'    => '/admin/post/add',
                                'defaults' => [
                                    'controller' => 'Blog\Controller\Posts',
                                    'action'     => 'add'
                                ]
                            ]
                        ], // end add post
            ] // end child routes
        ] // end blog route (main route)
    ] // end routes
] // end Router
```

And in the template displayed on "/en/admin/post/add" I have a call to `$this->url()`, that ends up printing `/%language%/admin/post/add`.

I have the language code available on `$language` on my template, and
I'd like to pass it on to `url()` so it properly constructs the the url using the spec.

Also, I'd like, if possible, not to specify the name of the route on my call to `url()`, so it uses the default one for `$this`.

How would I go around to accomplish this?

Thanks and regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While @marcosh answer works, since then I've found a simpler solution:

```
$this->url($this->route, ['language' => $language]);
```

Will output what I want. Seems clearer to me.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a segment route instead of a regex one and then use

```
$this->getHelperPluginManager()->getServiceLocator()->get('request')->getUri()->getPath();
```

in your view to print the actual route it's been used

Comment: Any reason why I should switch to a `segment` route? As far I can see it works perfectly with the route defined as it is...

Comment: @yivi you're rigth; there's no need to shitch to a `segment` route, but from your configuration I think that it is simpler and more suitable for what you are doing. That was just a suggestion